# Converting array of Doubles to an array of BigDecimals

Tags: java, arrays, double, type-conversion, biginteger

I am trying to convert an array of `Double` values to an array of `BigInteger` values, but I just can't figure out how exactly to tell java to create a new empty `BigInteger` array with the same length as the original array.

Comment: How do you create the BigInteger array? can't you just get the Double.size and then create the new array?

Comment: The issue was that I'd totally blanked out on how to do it; rather than spend 15 minutes looking it up in a maual I thought I'd just spend 5 minutes and ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BigInteger[] dest = new BigInteger[src.length];
```

where `src` is the original double array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the length of your `Double array`.. You can give it as the size to your `BigInteger` array..

```
BigInteger[] bigIntegerArr = new BigInteger[doubleArray.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BingInteger[] secondArray = new BigInteger[doublArray.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it with the length of your double array.

```
Double[] doubleArray = ...;
BigInteger[] bigIntArray = new BigInteger[doubleArray.length];
```